# Expectation of Difference in Means estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, causality, bias, unbiased-estimator

Given i.i.d. observations $(Y_i, X_i)$ where $Y_i$ is the response and $X_i$ is binary valued, the difference in means estimator is
$$
\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n_0} \sum_{i=1, X_i=0} Y_i - \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1, X_i=1} Y_i
$$
where $n_0 = \sum_{k=1} 1_{X_i = 0}$ and $n_1 = n-n_0$.

On [page 3 of these notes](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eswager/stats361.pdf), it is stated that

$$
E \left [ \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1, X_i=1} Y_i\right ] = E[Y_i|X_i=1].
$$

It's probably trivial but I am not seeing how this is true, we can rewrite
\begin{align*}
E \left [ \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1, X_i=1} Y_i\right ]
&=E \left [ \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i 1_{(X_i=1)}\right ]\\
&=E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{Y_i 1_{(X_i=1)}}{n_1/n}\right ]\\
&=E \left [ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{Y_i 1_{(X_i=1)}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n 1_{(X_j=1)}}\right ]
\end{align*}
How do we conclude that this is equal to $E[Y_i|X_i=1]$? As an aside, it is clear to me that since for any r.v. $Z$ and event $A$,
$$
E[Z|A] = \frac{E[Z1_{A}]}{P(A)}
$$
we can conclude that
$$
\frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1, X_i=1} Y_i
= \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i 1_{(X_i=1)}}{
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n 1_{(X_j=1)}}
 \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow }
\frac{E[Y_i 1_{X_i=1}]}{P(X_i=1)}
=E[Y_i|X_i=1]
$$

**update:** I think this is the correct approach:

\begin{align*}
E \left [ \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1, X_i=1} Y_i \right ]
&= E \left[ 
\frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1}^n E[Y_i 1_{(X_i = 1)}| X_1,\dots, X_n, n_1]
\right ]\\
&= E \left[ 
\frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{(X_i = 1)} E[Y_i | X_i = 1]
\right ]\\
&= E[Y_i | X_i = 1] E \left[ 
\frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{(X_i = 1)} 
\right ]\\
&= E[Y_i | X_i = 1] E \left[ 
1 
\right ]\\
&= E[Y_i | X_i = 1]
\end{align*}

Comment: A factor of $1/n$ disappeared from the expectation in the last equality, making it obviously untrue.  What did you intend to write?

Comment: @whuber i've removed that last line

Comment: The $Y_i$'s associated with $X_i=1$ are generated from the conditional distribution, aren't they?